# Resend registration email / reminder

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails, registration

I have two step verification set up on a particular website which works well in most cases.

However upon checking my registered users I notice that there are quite a few that are marked as 'unactivated'. This is most likely because they have not clicked the 'verify your email' link. Either due to them forgetting or the email has possibly gone into their junk folder?

These registrations are now stuck and more or less useless as I have no way of reminding the users other than manually sending an email to each of them.

I would like a way to send a 'reminder' to these users that they have to verify their email, is this possible? I haven't tried anything yet, however I was thinking of one of the following;

- another button in the admin area (resend activation email)
- a page with a single input box 'enter your email we will resend you the activation link'
- a cron job

I have seen a few plugins however none of them seem to offer this feature. Maybe I am missing something but it seems like this feature would have been requested and incorporated previously?

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you look at http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/regreminder
"Remind registered user who have not activated their account"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is something you need: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/regreminder

However, Joomla user password is, of course, encrypted. This is why system "knows" it just at the moment when you create it, i.e. only then it exists as text string for a while. Next moment it should be pulled out of the database to be resend to user in readable format, which is impossible. I am mentionig this second solution (when send username / password to mail is enabled) because it can be integrative part of registration. If you use this option - resending mails would not be of any use, since you (system) can not resend understandable password.

Anyway, I hope above mentioned extension helps.
Cheers!